# Directory 'Path' does not exist. Failed to start monitoring file changes

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, iis-7.5, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I just upgraded to Visual studio 2013 and found a new option to precompile and combine when publishing my asp.net webforms Project.

But upon publishing to my test server ajax control toolkit stopped working.

After looking in the event log I found the following:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 2014-12-12 16:06:48 
Event time (UTC): 2014-12-12 15:06:48 
Event ID: de260aa337ee442d877e35615225da8d 
Event sequence: 4 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 
....
Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: Directory 'E:\...\AppRoot\Controls\View' does not exist. Failed to start monitoring file changes.
   at System.Web.FileChangesMonitor.FindDirectoryMonitor(String dir, Boolean addIfNotFound, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Web.FileChangesMonitor.StartMonitoringPath(String alias, FileChangeEventHandler callback, FileAttributesData& fad)
   at System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency.Init(Boolean isPublic, String[] filenamesArg, String[] cachekeysArg, CacheDependency dependency, DateTime utcStart)
   at System.Web.Hosting.MapPathBasedVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheDependency(String virtualPath, IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart)
   at System.Web.ResponseDependencyList.CreateCacheDependency(CacheDependencyType dependencyType, CacheDependency dependency)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.CreateCacheDependencyForResponse()
   at System.Web.HttpCachePolicy.UpdateFromDependencies(HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.HttpCachePolicy.UpdateCachedHeaders(HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.HttpCachePolicy.GetHeaders(ArrayList headers, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.UpdateNativeResponse(Boolean sendHeaders)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.FinishRequestNotification(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context, RequestNotificationStatus& status)

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://.../Forms/Public/StartForm.aspx?_TSM_CombinedScripts_=True&v=P4sRFgGfV4Nfd4EZMC8du8QjF0BC31YW_Px8RQK42ys1&_TSM_Bundles_=&cdn=False 
    Request path: /Forms/Public/StartForm.aspx 
    User host address: X.X.X.X
    User: {BFBFFDD1-...-4697-85E7-69A522272D6D} 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Forms 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\app
```

The problem is that the directory `~\Controls\View` is not generated when I combine and precompile.
I have checked my web.config and it has no reference to `~\Controls\View`.

Why does this error only occur with the ajax control toolkit javascript reference and how to I resolve the error?

Comment: Have you downloaded the newest version of the toolkit?  It's possible that you have an older version that does not want to work with VS2013.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston im using the latest version + some fixes to make the tab control work correctly in IE8..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same error. I found this German page that describes the issue (Google Translate does a good job translating it):

http://gehirnwindung.de/post/2010/01/18/ASPNET-Precompilation-und-die-Fehlermeldung-Directory-does-not-exist-Failed-to-start-monitoring-file-changes.aspx

The solution was simple, just create the missing directory during the build. I just added a MakeDir line to my publish profile and the problem went away.